# fastlane: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, macos-catalina

I use latest fastlane version 2.141 and

```
 --------------------------- | -------------------------------------------------------------- |
| OS                          | 10.15                                                          |
| Ruby                        | 2.6.3                                                          |
| Bundler?                    | false                                                          |
| Git                         | git version 2.22.0                                             |
| Installation Source         | /usr/local/bin/fastlane                                        |
| Host                        | Mac OS X 10.15 (19A603)                                        |
| Ruby Lib Dir                | /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib |
| OpenSSL Version             | LibreSSL 2.8.3                                                 |
| Is contained                | false                                                          |
| Is homebrew                 | false                                                          |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false                                                          |
| Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/                    |
| Xcode Version               | 11.3.1                                                         |
```

I lanched fastalene "fastlane build" and expect get local app file.
But I got error.

```
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/3c/mlppx6h92875_71f3w39c8v00000gn/T/gym_config20200203-9409-1rhcgra.plist -archivePath '/Users/hq/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-02-03/BLU 2020-02-03 17.00.39.xcarchive' -exportPath /var/folders/3c/mlppx6h92875_71f3w39c8v00000gn/T/gym_output20200203-9409-fu1vea
497 2020-02-03 17:02:27.381 xcodebuild[10097:747090] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/3c/mlppx6h92875_71f3w39c8v00000gn/T/BLU_2020-02-03_17-02-27.380.xcdistributionlogs'.
498 2020-02-03 17:02:27.488 xcodebuild[10097:747090] [MT] IDEDistributionMethodManager: -[IDEDistributionMethodManager orderedDistributionMethodsForTask:archive:]: Error = Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodManagerErrorDomain Code=2 "Unknown Distribution Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Distribution Error}
499 error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {}, but found app-store
500 Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {}, but found app-store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {}, but found app-store}
```

My fastlane file is simple

```
  desc "Build application"
  lane :build do
    install_provisioning_profile(path: ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILE"])
    import_certificate(certificate_path: ENV["CERT_PATH"],
                       certificate_password: ENV["CERT_PWD"],
                       keychain_name: ENV["KEYCHAIN_NAME"],
                       keychain_password: ENV["HQ_PWD"])
    gym(
      scheme: ENV["SCHEME"],
      clean: true,
      output_directory: "build",
      export_options: {
        method: 'app-store'
      }
    )
```

In detaile logs of fastlane I find out strange message:

```
e' from project 'BLU')
    cd /Users/zakabluk/Documents/git/githubBLU/mobile-ios/app/BLU
    builtin-RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/zakabluk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BLU-gvvvkwpjdlklocherkkkepucneic/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BLU/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/BLU.app
note: Execution policy exception registration failed and was skipped: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" (in target 'BLU' from project 'BLU')
```

maybe this help for understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have Fixed when:

For target and progect set: skip install - yes (Build settings) .

Delete exceed rows for entitlements .

and changed script for Strip Architectures:

```
# This removes the unsupported archetypes from frameworks on the build phase.
echo "Target architectures: $ARCHS"
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
echo $(lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")
FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH="$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-tmp"
# remove simulator's archs if location is not simulator's directory
case "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}" in
*"iphonesimulator")
  echo "No need to remove archs"
  ;;
*)
  if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "i386") ; then
  lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "i386" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  echo "i386 architecture removed"
  rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  mv "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  fi
  if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "x86_64") ; then
  lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "x86_64" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  echo "x86_64 architecture removed"
  rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  mv "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
  fi
  ;;
esac
echo "Completed for executable $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
echo $(lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")
done
```